Someone with problem related to new feature "Require Face ID and hide app" on iOS 18?
I have a problem in my app on iOS 18: when the app is hidden, internal deeplinks don't work.. Someone have the same problem or has been resolved this issue in your app?

Install iOS 18
Select an app and "Require Face ID and hide app"
internal deeplinks don't work


By "internal" you mean app-internal?

hey, i've the same issue. I just found this link, but it hasn't been helpful yet: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/763107
